# Logs with java.util.logger are affected by CVE-2021-44228?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm migrating all the slf4j dependencies affected by the vulnerability and I'm wondering if in the projects that the log is by java.util.logger (some of these projects are used as dependencies of others) affects some kind below. In theory no, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Whole different packages, java.util doesnt use log4j at all.